# How to change the bootstrap's well color?

Tags: css, colors, background-color

I just started learning php and I dont know how to change the color of well.
Doing research I found this

```
.well.homefull{

background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}
```

But I dont know where to put it and how to use it with

```
<div class="well">
```

if I simply put it before div class=well it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override the css rules of the boostrap `well` class.

To do this, you'll need to create a custom css file and [call this external style sheet from the html page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

For example :

```css
.well {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well">
    Some content
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT** :

Or in one page, you could put the style rules between `<style></style>` tag (take care to put the overriding style rules after the call of bootstrap sources) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Developping JazZ Sheet</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .well {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="well">
        some content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didnt worked, what am I doing wrong?
 I put .well code between <style></style>
 
 <style>
 .well {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
}
 </style>
 
 
Then in <body> I put this

<body style="">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well">fugg</div>
 
But well color is still white

Comment: Ok, just put the `<style></style>` tag after the call of bootstrap css. It must work.

Comment: @MahigYahok See the edited answer for an example in one page.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Do you know how to change color of well borders as well? Color changes but borders are still white

Comment: @MahigYahok You're welcome. If it works and if it solved your question, validate and upvote my answer please. For border color, use the `border-color` attribute as you did it for the background color. i.e. : `border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);`